# How does 'dir' output files?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, glob

I would like to find out more on how 'dir' in command prompt works. I have a folder with a 365 files, one for each day of the year, and 'dir' spits out the files in order, *except* for 2023-01-12, which appears before 2023-01-01. Interestingly, 2023-02-12 appears in order, as does all other files that occur on the 12th of the month, so I was curious to see why 2023-01-12 appears before everything else. Is the reason hardware related? Software related? Does it have to do with how 'dir' was implemented?

[image]

Tried using 'dir' command, behavior is inconsistent. I am aware the the 'dir' command has arguments to sort via [alphabetically, date, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir), but why does the default 'dir' order this one file name "2023-01-12" out of order?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603

Comment: [Default file order of "dir" command in Windows console](https://superuser.com/a/1195976/241386)